# Abstract data type in Oracle 11g ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904

Oracle Version:  `Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0` - Production

```
    create type address_ty as object
    (street varchar2(50),
     city varchar2(50),
     state varchar2(25),
     postalcode integer);

    create or replace type person_ty as object
    (FullName varchar2(50),
     BirthDate date,
     Address address_ty,
     member function CalcAge (BirthDate in DATE) return number,
     PRAGMA RESTRICT_REFERENCES (CALCAGE, WNDS));

    create or replace type body person_ty as 
    member function CalcAge (BirthDate DATE) return number is
    begin
       return round(sysdate - BirthDate);
    end;
    end;
    /

    create table customer (customerId integer,
                       Person person_ty);

    describe customer;

    select attr_name, length, attr_type_name from user_type_attrs where type_name = 'PERSON_TY';

    select attr_name, length, attr_type_name from user_type_attrs where type_name = 'ADDRESS_TY';

    insert into customer values (1, person_ty('ABC', '01-JAN-95', address_ty('MG Road', 'Bangalore', 'KA', 560001)));

    select person.FullName from customer;
```

The above statement displays an error -

> ORA-00904: "PERSON"."FULLNAME": invalid identifier

How to resolve the error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to qualify the column with the table, so it doesn't try to interpret `person` as a table name; and it needs to be an alias (not entirely sure why):

```
select c.person.FullName from customer c;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4788/3).